# Slow SQL transaction getting latest timestamp rows from table in Postgres

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I am having trouble with a slow transaction in Postgres trying to retrieve the latest prices of the catalogproducts that have a buy that is greater than their sell.  It is a rather large table at this point, over 2 million rows.  I have this for historical purposes.  What I am currently using is:

```
select * from ta_price a
  join (
   select catalogproduct_id, max(timestamp) ts
     from ta_price
    group by catalogproduct_id
       ) b on a.catalogproduct_id = b.catalogproduct_id
          and a.timestamp = b.ts
          AND buy > sell;
```

catalogproduct_id is a Foreign Key to catalogproduct table.

Out of 2201760 total rows, it selects 2296 rows.  The total runtime  is 181,792.705 ms.

Any insight on how to improve this?

**Edit:**

I am blown away by all the answers!  I want to also qualify this question more under the realm of the Django ORM.  I am struggling to incorporate a composite key (or the like) on this table (using catalogproduct_id and timestamp).  I have a primary key that is an autoincrementing index, which I guess is as good as not having none at all.

**Edit 2:**
After adding a partial index that @Erwin suggested, 
`CREATE INDEX my_partial_idx ON ta_price (catalogproduct_id, timestamp)
 WHERE buy > sell;`, I am using the query from @wildplasser for around 10-12 second query time.  For further clarification, my table is snapshots of prices (buy and sell) of products over time.  At any given time, I want to know what products currently (as of their latest snapshot time) have a `buy > sell`.

Comment: Initial runs of the queries has @wildplasser as about half of everyone's time, while still respecting the expected resultset.  I still do not have a true index because of trying to work within Django.

Comment: Django or not - if you want more speed, you need one or more fitting indexes. But first things first: what is your postgres version?

Comment: Yeah, I got your partial index in there but with @wildplasser query.  It is down to around 10 seconds now!!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Revised answer after some consideration

```
SELECT *
  FROM ta_price a
  JOIN (
   SELECT catalogproduct_id, max(timestamp) ts
     FROM ta_price
    GROUP BY catalogproduct_id
        ) b ON a.catalogproduct_id = b.catalogproduct_id
           AND a.timestamp = b.ts
           AND a.buy > a.sell;
```

`buy`and `sell` are not qualified in your question. Depending on the selectivity of `buy > sell` you can speed up the query by adding the same `WHERE`-clause to the subselect. 
However, this yields **different results**. I add it on the off chance, that you might have overlooked it:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ta_price a
  JOIN (
   SELECT catalogproduct_id, max(timestamp) ts
     FROM ta_price
    WHERE buy > sell
    GROUP BY catalogproduct_id
        ) b ON a.catalogproduct_id = b.catalogproduct_id
           AND a.timestamp = b.ts
 WHERE a.buy > a.sell;
```

Either way, a simple index like @Will implies will help:
<strike>CREATE INDEX my_idx ON ta_price (catalogproduct_id, timestamp);</strike>

There is a superior approach, though.
An unconditional `max()` in the subselect will result in a sequential table scan regardless of indexes. Such an operation will never be fast with 2.2m rows.
The `JOIN` condition, combined with the `WHERE` clause of the outer `SELECT`, will profit from an index like the one above. Depending on the selectivity of `buy > sell` a [partial index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html) will be a little or substantially faster and, correspondingly, smaller on disc and in RAM:

```
CREATE INDEX my_partial_idx ON ta_price (catalogproduct_id, timestamp)
 WHERE buy > sell;
```

The order of the columns in the index does not matter in this case. It will also speed ab my second variant of the query.

You mentioned the table was for "historic" purposes? If that means no new data, you could speed things up greatly with a *materialized view*.

---

On a side note: I would not use `timestamp` as a column name. It is allowed in PostgreSQL, but it's a [reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in all SQL standards.

---

OK, **first things last**: for a table of 2.2m rows you need **way more** resources than postgres has out of the box.

- Look at your postgresql.conf file and inspect the settings for `shared_buffers` and `work_mem` for a start.
- Consult the [postgres wiki for performance tuning](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server)
- Consult the fine manual on [ressource consumption](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-resource.html)
- Consult the fine manual on [planner costs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-CONSTANTS)
- Increase these statistics setting:
  `ALTER TABLE tmp.ta_price ALTER COLUMN buy SET STATISTICS 1000;

  ALTER TABLE tmp.ta_price ALTER COLUMN sell SET STATISTICS 1000;

  ALTER TABLE tmp.ta_price ALTER COLUMN ts SET STATISTICS 1000;`

  Then run `ANALYZE tmp.ta_price;`
- Be sure that [autovacuum](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/routine-vacuuming.html) is running. If in doubt, run `VACUUM ANALYZE ta_price` and see if it had an effect.

  ---

I have played with the test setup of wildplasser (**which was very helpful!**) on a pg 8.4 installation with limited ressources.
Here are the  **total runtimes fom `EXPLAIN ANYLYZE`**

```
Erwin 1)        901.487 ms  
wildplasser 1) 1148.045 ms  
A.H.           2922.113 ms
```

Variant 2 with the additional (buy > sell) clause:

```
Erwin 2)        536.678 ms  
wildplasser 2)  809.215 ms
```

#### With partial index:

```
Erwin 1)       1166.793 ms  -- slower (!), than unexpected
```

<sub>Probably planner costs are off, this test db cluster is optimized for main db which 
has way more resources.</sub>

```
wildplasser 1) 1122.609 ms -- rest is faster as expected  

Erwin 2)        481.487 ms  
wildplasser 2)  769.887 ms
```

#### Resumé

A.H.'s version takes much longer (same result as you reported). Window functions tend to be slow, especially on older versions of postgres. My alternative query is twice as fast, as expected. Question is, if the different results are desired - maybe not.

Anyway, that were 300k rows. Query takes 0.5 - 1s on version 8.4 with limited resources (but proper settings, mostly) on a 5 year old server. With a decent machine and decent settings (enough RAM!) you should bring it down to **under 10s** at least.

Comment: Not having much luck on getting increased performance.  The historic aspect is the necessity to graph buy/sell prices over time.  I keep adding new prices/timestamps in this table when taking my snapshots.

Comment: @bdilly: That's odd. I actually tested this on posgtres 9.0 with a medium size sample of 5000 rows. A partial index should definitely speed up things. If you can describe in more detail, what you are trying to retrieve exactly (buy > sell?) and add more numbers,  more ideas might surface here. (Edit the question for that!)

Comment: I did a test run yesterday with approx 4M rows. Running time was a few seconds as expected. [I'll add the results when I get home] Maybe the query plan will shift to hashmap if the number of expected matches in the inner loop gets smaller. Window functions perform relatively bad, because the will not be pulled out of the subquery (also depends on the aggregates being used; semantically hard to decide for the optimiser) . Might have been changed in 9.1.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * from ta_price a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM ta_price b
  WHERE b.catalogproduct_id = a.catalogproduct_id
    AND b.timestamp > a.timestamp
    -- AND b.buy > b.sell -- Not clear if OP wants this
    )
AND a.buy > a.sell
;
```

An index on (catalogproduct_id, timestamp) is probably beneficial.
The extra condition "AND b.buy > b.sell" in the subquery will probably be needed (the text in the OP is not clear about what is actually needed).

UPDATE: "timestamp" is a reserved word. I changed it a bit. Also added testdata.

```
DROP SCHEMA tmp cascade;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;

CREATE TABLE tmp.ta_price
    ( catalogproduct_id INTEGER NOT NULL
    , tttimestamp timestamp NOT NULL
    , buy DECIMAL (10,2)
    , sell DECIMAL (10,2)
    );
INSERT INTO tmp.ta_price(catalogproduct_id,tttimestamp,buy,sell)
    SELECT serie_n
    , serie_t
    , serie_v + ((100* random()) - 30)
    , serie_v + ((100* random()) - 20)
    FROM generate_series (1,10000) serie_n
    , generate_series ( '2011-09-01 00:00:00' , '2011-10-01 00:00:00' , '1 day' ::interval) serie_t
    , generate_series ( 100 , 100 ) serie_v
    ;
DELETE FROM tmp.ta_price WHERE random() < 0.02;

CREATE INDEX tmptmp ON tmp.ta_price (catalogproduct_id,tttimestamp);

-- there may be some duplicate records: clear them
DELETE FROM tmp.ta_price a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tmp.ta_price b
    WHERE b.catalogproduct_id = a.catalogproduct_id
    AND b.tttimestamp = a.tttimestamp
    AND b.ctid > a.ctid
    );

DROP INDEX tmp.tmptmp ;

ALTER TABLE tmp.ta_price
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (catalogproduct_id,tttimestamp)
    ;

EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT * from tmp.ta_price a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM tmp.ta_price b
  WHERE b.catalogproduct_id = a.catalogproduct_id
    AND b.tttimestamp > a.tttimestamp
    -- AND b.buy > b.sell -- Not clear if OP wants this
    )
AND a.buy > a.sell
;
```

Queryplan: (for 300K records in ta_price)

```
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=0.00..8607.82 rows=67508 width=38) (actual time=457.486..482.943 rows=4052 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on ta_price a  (cost=0.00..6381.34 rows=101262 width=38) (actual time=0.027..80.256 rows=123142 loops=1)
         Filter: (buy > sell)
   ->  Index Scan using ta_price_pkey on ta_price b  (cost=0.00..10.57 rows=506 width=12) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=123142)
         Index Cond: ((b.catalogproduct_id = a.catalogproduct_id) AND (b.tttimestamp > a.tttimestamp))
 Total runtime: 483.325 ms
(6 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding an index on catalogproduct_id and timestamp. Looks like it's table scanning to me with no other information.

Answer (score 0):

Your query will join the table to itself in order to get the maximum. You might give "[Window Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/tutorial-window.html)" a try to prevent this - perhaps they work better in your case:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, rank() OVER w
    FROM ta_price                             
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY catalogproduct_id ORDER BY timestamp DESC)
) c WHERE c.rank = 1 AND c.buy > c.sell;
```

Comment: I utilized this approach at first, and although correct results, it was slower than my current approach.